# why my website not showing in windows phone browser?

Tags: wordpress, browser, windows-phone

I deployed my website with WordPress and updated my time early time ago, after updating my site showing in android and windows very good but in a windows phone browser it is not showing; it is a big question for me why this problem happened???

my site URL: http://kookarnik.com

Comment: Not showing means what? does it means site is not loading at all? or is there any error. did you try by changing theme?

Comment: @user3251472 it means white page at all. yes with other theme it work fine, i know the problem is in my themebut i wan't to know what is it?

Answer (score 0):

OK. this is how you can resolve it.

List item

1. login to admin panel
2. disable all plugins.
3. see you site is working.
4. if it is working enable plugins one by one. you can find who can crete the cause. update perticuler plugin on use alternative.
5. same time try with different windows mobile also. problem can be in browser as well

Comment: tanks for your answer. but i know my theme is the problem. i need know what file (css or js) make the problem for windows phone Browser,